# get() from an Entry Box returns 'None'

Tags: python, exception, tkinter, error-handling

recently I began to work with tkinter. I try to create a Grade manager and when I try to save the input from an Entry box, but every way I try, the result is an error or 'None'

```
 def check_value(self,Input_Name):
        Name = Input_Name.get()
        print(Name)
    def add_Student(self, window):
        print("Yes")
        Input_Name = tk.Entry(window, bg='blue').pack()
    
        Button(window, text="Show", command=lambda: self.check_value(Input_Name)).pack()
```

For this piece of code the following error is :

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1883, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 28, in
>
> Button(window, text="Show", command=lambda: self.check_value(window.Input_Name)).pack()   File
> "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 20, in
> check_value
> Name = Input_Name.get() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: what does the `InputName` param look like when its created

Comment: Even if I try to get the Input_Name with Name = input(Input_Name), the result is 'None'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the `Input_Name` to the result that is returned by `.pack()` method of the widget, not to the widget itself. `.pack()` method returns nothing. Consequently, you are trying to `.get()` something from a Nonetype object instead of a `tk.Entry`.

You need to assign the `tk.Entry` to the `Input_Name` variable first, and then just call method pack on the variable. Here is an example of fixed code:

```
def check_value(self,Input_Name):
    Name = Input_Name.get()
    print(Name)
def add_Student(self, window):
    print("Yes")
    Input_Name = tk.Entry(window, bg='blue')
    Input_Name.pack()
    Button(window, text="Show", command=lambda: self.check_value(Input_Name)).pack()
```